# How to queue or postpone a function call when waiting for a promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm having problems with using a value that is set inside an `$http.get`. Since it is asynchronous I cannot acces the value when the promise hasn't returned. Is there a way to call a function, check if a required value is already defined, if not, wait, otherwise continue with the function?

I've tried to use $q.all but I don't have an array of promises, I only have 1 promise and a function that gets called before the promise is returned but requires the promises result. I cannot use `then()` after the promise since I want to call the function multiple times while the promise is only called on startup. Here is a basic overview of my html, app.js and the service where the problem occurs:

html:

```
<div data-tool="contactForm" data-language="english">
    <h1>{{'heading' | translate }}</h1>
</div>
```

app.js:

```
mainApp.directive('tool', ['translationService', function (translationService) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            //load current translation files with the giver paramters
            translationService.loadDefaultTranslation(attrs.language);
        }
    }
}]);

mainApp.filter('translate', function (translationService) {
    'use strict';
    return function (input) {
        //translate the given input
        return translationService.doTranslation(input);
    };
});
```

translationService.js:

```
//Called once on startup
var translation;
var loadDefaultTranslation = function (language) {

    $http.get(language + '.json').success(function (data) {
        translation = data;
    });
}

//This is called multiple times from within a filter
var doTranslation = function(input)
{
    return translation[input];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add condition in your function doTranslation.
And you return input when translation isn't set.

If your are using angular-ui-router, you can use i18n module like [ngBabelfish](https://github.com/dhoko/angular-ngBabelfish)